# How to validate data with a Model by POST request sent over REST call(without ActiveForm) - Yii2

Tags: php, rest, validation, yii, active-form

I am creating a **Yii** application in which data is being sent over `POST` request to my server via REST calls. As there is no `ActiveForm` coming in the scenario, what is the best approach to validate data with Model class for which data is being sent and after successful validation, it will be saved into db table.

I had gone through official docs but didn't find anything related. As inbuilt approach is given for `ActiveForm` `$model->validate()`, I am wondering if something like this is there as easy as calling a function for the data posted without `ActiveForm` to validate that data with my `Model` class.

I know it can be done with `isset($_POST['somefield']` but it is a bit traditional approach & to be repeated for each field (personally I feel it's a boring activity to check if data is posted in a field and then perform validation for each field separately).

Is there any official doc which I missed? Or if it is not given in doc, what would be the best approach?

Suggest me something to create code magic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, After doing some more research I found solution to the said problem as below:

```
    $model = new AppDetails();
    $model->setAttributes(Yii::$app->request->post(), false);
    if($model->validate() && $model->save())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

As per [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#setAttributes()-detail) docs, `setAttributes()` does **Sets the attribute values in a massive way.** Here, I created new object for my model class and then sets attributes coming over post request.

Once I set the attributes to my model class object, I could then `validate()` them and also save them directly in db just calling `save()` applicable only after successful validation.

However, with this you must have to send all attributes as per rules section of your model (including primary key auto incremented values. Also you can set them later if you are not sending it over rest call like `$model->id=''`). Otherwise, `validate()` will return false.

Being more specific about `$model->load()` it returns true if data is posted from a `Form`(as per what I understood from my coding experience) with fields set with object of **Model class** (see more [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail)). `load()` automatically then loads the `formName` in background scenario set by Yii developers.

You may try doing like `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` with data sent over REST call, It will always return false because attributes are not set.

I think I have explained solution to my above said problem. Do point out in case anything is wrong or not well understandable.

I hope it helps future readers with same issue.

Comment: I was struggling why $model->load doesn''t work, you actually answered it in details. Thank you very much.

Comment: @progdo I'm glad I helped someone atleast. :)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a traditional...

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
    //$model loaded with post data and validated
}
```

...?

Comment: `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()` works with `ActiveForm` i.e. when data is being submitted from view with fields as instance of `Activeform` with the model's class object as arguement. Since it's a rest call hence no scene of `ActiveForm` is there.

Comment: `$form->field($model, 'device_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])` See here, `$form` is an instance of `ActiveForm` and `$model` is an instance of my model class. This can be done when there is a view for that action and data is sent from this view to controller.

Comment: That's wrong, please read documentation before minusing ppl wiling to help you. `$model->load` can be interpreted as `if (isset($_POST['FormName'])) $model->attributes = $_POST['FormName'];` It got absolutely nothing related to `ActiveForm`. You can use it in REST as well, just prefix your attributes and pass prefix to `load()` or just assign `$_POST` to attributes.

Comment: @ineersa I did tried that already. `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()` returns `true` or `false` and for me as per the answer given always returns `false'. I don't think still this is correct answer posted. This was just posted thinking that I didn't tried that. But it's not like that. Well when this answer was posted, I already had solved my issue. I was just  waiting for the good one. See my answer, and I think it is more clearly understandable too. Please do me a favour by pointing out issues in my answer if any. Cheers :)